# 「bash: ./configure: そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません」と出ます。

Tags: linux, bash, debian

お世話になります。
fw backupsというバックアップ用のOSSをDebian 10にインストールしようとしているのですが、
`fwbackups`フォルダーに入ってroot権限を取得したあとに、

`# ./configure --prefix=/usr`を実行しますと
`bash: ./configure: そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません`と出ます。

また、root権限を取得せずに`$ sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr`

を実行しますと、
`sudo: ./configure: コマンドが見つかりません`と出ます。

どのようにすれば`./configure --prefix=/usr`を実行できるでしょうか。ご教授願ます。

Comment: まず、その `./configure` というファイルは存在しますか？　`ls ./configure` でヒットしますか？

Comment: `autogen.sh` というファイルが存在する場合は、まず `./autogen.sh` を実行します。正常終了すると `configure` script が作成されているはずです。

Comment: @metropolis  様　`./autogen.sh`でも実行できませんでしたので、`Python-paramiko`をインストールしてから`./autogen.sh`を実行しますと`./configure`も実行できました。

Comment: @nekketsuuu 様　metropolis様にリプライしました通りです。お二人ともありがとうございました！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[インストール手順](https://github.com/stewartadam/fwbackups/blob/master/INSTALL.md#building-from-source) を参照すると、ソースコードからビルドする場合には `configure` を実行する**前**に
`./autogen.sh` を実行するように、と記載があります。

[ソースコード](https://github.com/stewartadam/fwbackups) をダウンロード/展開した直後には `configure` ファイルは含まれていないので、
上述の `autogen.sh` を実行する事で生成されるはずです。

Comment: 様　`Python-paramiko`をインストールしたあとに`./autogen.sh`を実行しましたらできました！ありがとうございました！