# fwbackupsで / ディレクトリにRestoreしたいのですが、エラーが出ます

Tags: linux, bash, debian

fwbackupsで`/`にRestoreしたいのですが、エラーが出ます。OSはDebianです。
どのようにしましたらRestoreできるのでしょうか？ご教授願ます。

追記　[teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/229405?modal=q-comp)にもマルチポストさせていただきます。ご了承くださいませ。

**エラーログ**

```
12月 14 01:54:32 :: INFO : Starting restore operation
12月 14 01:54:32 :: WARNING : You do not have read and write permissions on the destination `/' - if you backed up system files, this operation may fail.
12月 14 01:54:32 :: ERROR : Error(s) occurred while restoring certain files or folders.
Please check the traceback below to determine if any files are incomplete or missing.
12月 14 01:54:32 :: ERROR : Traceback: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fwbackups/operations/restore.py", line 150, in start
    fh.extractall(encode(self.options['Destination']))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 2081, in extractall
    self.extract(tarinfo, path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 2118, in extract
    self._extract_member(tarinfo, os.path.join(path, tarinfo.name))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 2202, in _extract_member
    self.makelink(tarinfo, targetpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 2279, in makelink
    os.unlink(targetpath)
OSError: [Errno 13] 許可がありません: '/bin'

12月 14 01:54:32 :: INFO : Finished restore operation
12月 14 01:54:32 :: INFO : Canceling the current operation!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

エラーメッセージは非常に重要なので「エラーが出た」で済ませずに、翻訳にかけてでも内容をチェックするようにしてください。

> ```
> WARNING : You do not have read and write permissions on the destination `/' - if you backed up system files, this operation may fail.
> ERROR : Error(s) occurred while restoring certain files or folders.
> ```

"`/` ディレクトリに対して読み書きの権限がない" と出ています。通常 `/` ディレクトリに対して一般ユーザーでは書き込むことができません。実行時のユーザー権限を確認してください。

[他の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/61402) では本来不要な場面で `sudo` を使っていたりするので、Linuxにおけるアクセス権限(パーミッション)周りに関する仕組みを調べてもらうとよいかなと思います。

Comment: 様　ありがとうございます。今の私にはfwbackupsのユーザー権限をrootにする力はないので、一旦諦めて一からLinuxを勉強いたします。